# Determine if Relation $R$ is reflective, symmetric or transitive

Tags: relations, symmetry

Let $X = \{3, 5, 9\}, Y = \{2, 3, 6, 7\}$ and the relation, $R = \{(x, y) | y \leqslant x\}.$

For the relation, I manage to come out with $R = \{(2,3), (2,5), (2,9), (3,3), (3,5), (3,9), (6,9), (7,9)\}.$

However, I have difficulties in determining if $R$ is **reflective**, **symmetric** or **transitive**.

I think $R$ is **not reflective** because not all loops are present, *i.e.* only $(3,3)$ is present. However, I saw some online source stated that $\leqslant$ is reflective, which confused me.

I also think that $R$ is **not symmetric** because not all $(x,y)∈R$
implies $(y,x)∈R$, *e.g.* $(3,5)$ presents but not $(5,3)$.

As for transitive, I think it is **transitive** too because $(2,3)$ and $(3,5)$ are in the set, as well as $(2,5)$ too.

I'm not sure if I get all these correct or not. Really appreciate if you all could help me identify these. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you should change the order of the elements in the pairs of $R$. The first element should be from $X$, the second one from $Y$. For example instead of the pair $(2,3)$ it should be $(3,2)$.

Comment: Your set $R$ should read $R = \{(3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7)\}.$

Comment: After Mark pointed out, my initial thoughts would be R={(3,2),(3,3),(5,2),(5,3),(9,2),(9,3),(9,6),(9,7)}. May i know why should it be read as R = {(3,3), (3,6), (3,7), (5,6), (5,7)} please?

Comment: A relation $R$ over a set $X$ is reflexive iff $(x,x)\in R$ for every $x\in X$. In this context $\leq$ defined on e.g. $X=\mathbb R$ is reflexive. But in your case we are not dealing with a relation over a set $X$ (which is a subset of $X\times X$). We are dealing with a relation from a set $A$ to a set $B\neq A$. Then you cannot speak of "reflexive relation". Actually the same is true for the concepts "symmetric" and "transitive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to definitions of [reflexive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), [symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) and [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) it makes no sense to check on these properties.

This because here we are **not** dealing with a *[binary relation over a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation)* $X$.

Instead we are dealing with a relation $R$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$ (i.e. $R\subseteq A\times B$) where $A\neq B$.

If you still insist on checking then you could interpret $R$ as a relation over set $A\cup B$.

That trick has no consequences for the check itself if it comes to symmetry and transitivity, but from $A\neq B$ it follows directly that $R$ will not be a reflexive relation on $A\cup B$.